# Search and then delete from two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have two tables which have member data (linked with 'member_id' column)

I need to search for all records where the `email` column ends in '.pl'. I then need to delete all records from the two tables for this (based on the 'member_id').

Is it possible to complete this in one SQL statement?

```
SELECT member_id
FROM exp_members 
WHERE email LIKE '%.pl'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
delete t1, t2
from exp_members t1
join table2 t2 on t1.member_id = t2.member_id
where t1.email LIKE '%.pl'
```

Comment: Thank you, but I get the error:  #1093 - You can't specify target table 't1' for update in FROM clause

Comment: I did not know one of the tables was your source table. Then the query gets way more easy.

Answer (score -1):

```
Delete from Members where Member_id = (SELECT member_id
FROM exp_members 
WHERE email LIKE '%.pl')
```

Comment: u'd better use `IN` statement not equal

Comment: because multiple rows will return